# Suppressing JSLint Strict Violation for using this in an inner function called with the correct context

Tags: javascript, jslint

Consider this simple javascript code - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/c2DRP/

Validating the code with JSLint triggers the jslint "Strict violation" error on the usage of `this` inside the `inner` function. However, that function is invoked with the correct non global context.

So, I wonder how do I suppress this JSLint error for that particular function?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a working code example on jsfiddle for example so we can test it on JSLint and see the error ourselves?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSLint does not support this, you'll have to just ignore it.  The community fork called [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) has an option called `validthis` which can suppress the warnings in cases like yours:

> > This option suppresses warnings about possible strict violations when the code is running in strict mode and you use this in a non-constructor function. You should use this option—in a function scope only—when you are positive that your use of this is valid in the strict mode (for example, if you call your function using Function.call).

Comment: Thanks. Does JSHint have all the rules that JSLint has? Including the `var` rule, advertised here - http://anton.kovalyov.net/2011/02/20/why-i-forked-jslint-to-jshint/

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a reference to "this", like:

```
function f() {
  "use strict";
  var ref = this;

  function inner() {
    alert(ref.msg);
  }

  inner.call({ msg:'hello' });
}
```